# jQuery animation problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have relatively positioned list items in a list, I'm trying to animate them and when the element goes beyond the container I want to return it to container's starting point, here's a code, animation seems to be working but when I do the check (if the element is out of container) in the callback and I try to change the css of the current element it doesn't do anything, element stays in the same place and continues to move in the same direction.

here's my code:

```
var lis = $("#container").find('li');
(function(){
    var curFunc = arguments.callee;         
    lis.animate({
            left:"+=1px"
    },10,function(){            
        var currentLi = $(this);
        if(currentLi.position().left > 995){                                    
            currentLi.css({"left" : "-=900px"});    
        }
        curFunc();
    });         
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your marquee animation seams to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSDtH/2/).

Comment: I just realized it was a jquery version that caused the problem, in earlier versions of jquery it doesn't work

Comment: I'm glad my demo helped you to sort it out :)